# Getting session authenticity token via ajax (rails, jquery)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, authentication, forms-authentication

I wish to authenticate a user without having the page reloaded, and having the user submit a given form.

However, the problem that I immediately run into here is that the authenticity token typically gets set when the page is reloaded.

I need the authenticity token for the form submission, but i do not have it yet because the page is yet to reload.

I figure this cannot be that rare - anyone has any idea on how to resolve this?

1 idea could be getting rails to pass back the authenticity token after authentication, but i do not know how to access it from the controller

> 1) not logined user sees form
>
> 2) not logined user types in message and submit
>
> 3) facebox asking for authentication
>
> 4) after authentication, submit form automatically without refreshing
>
> 5) //but authenticity token is needed for form submission, which is not there yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decided to answer my own question w a potential solution, please feel free to jump in:

in my authentication controller action, i looked at the auth token in the session data, parsed it. The code is as follows:

```
cookie_data = session.to_hash.clone
auth_token=cookie_data[:_csrf_token]
#pass the auth_token via json, store it in global object, for any future ajax call to use
```

what do you think?